# Sharepoint Designer 2013: Workflow stops when current item is a Lookup Field

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-2013

**Objective**: Create a Workflow that Rename a Document in the Library.

My Document Library is in a sub site, is a child. This library have two lookup columns, and they refer to a list in the main site, the parent. That is, a library that have lookup field a list in other site. These lookup field, I will use to rename a file.

**Problem**: in my worflow every action that use [%CurrentItem:LookupField%], it does not follow. The workflow stops. Fail.

I can't understand the origin of that error.

Any information will be helpfull.

Workaround: Use REST CALL as you can see in the know issue. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/sharepoint-server-2013-known-issues-HA102919021.aspx?ss-src=featuredhelp&ss=3f1a5755-0dad-4a34-8758-904329f5e4c9

Comment: My objective is now complete. \o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a know issue, as you can see in the o365 forum.
community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/p/206482/754001.aspx

Know issues of SPD 2013:http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/sharepoint-server-2013-known-issues-HA102919021.aspx?ss-src=featuredhelp&ss=3f1a5755-0dad-4a34-8758-904329f5e4c9

**Workaround: Use Rest Call Action.**

I need the title, that is in my lookup field, but my workflow cant get this information. No if this lookup field is looking for a list in other level site.

So I will use REST CALL to my library, and get THE ID of my lookup field, and then i will do other REST CALL to that list, using the ID, and it will return my title of this item. :D

*Looks easy @_@ but i am not sure how to do a rest call from the workflow D:*

*I failed @_@... Now when I have to request something in other list, i got "Unauthorized"... really? D:*

**FINAL SOLUTION:** We did it... You have to set app permissions for your workflow. you Can see how do it here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
**Don't forget:** If you want to access a list in a TOP level site (main), you have to set this permission there, in the top level site. Why i am saying it? because, I set this permission on the same site where my workflow started, so when it wanted to request something in the main site, my request fail. So pay atection when do it. :)

If you have problems, count with me. \o/

Comment: How did you do the second step "Wrapping actions inside an App Step
"??